# Batch Script- Passing a delimited string

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scripting, cmd

I am using a linux script that takes in a delimited string and loops through each value ...

`MYIFS=','
    IFS=$MYIFS read -ra CONTACTS <<< "$1"
    for i in "${CONTACTS[@]}"; do
        echo "... try sending to contact $i"
        $ADB shell am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.shellms/.sendSMS -e contact "$i" -e msg "$2" 1>/dev/null
    done`

Does anyone have an idea how i would be able to do something similarly on windows?

I need to be able to invoke the script from the commandline ie

stackoverflow.bat "2342342342,23423424234,2123123123" "Message to Send"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help :

```
@echo off  

for %%a in (%~1) do echo try sending : [ %2 ] to  [ %%a ]
```

Now you have to find the Windows command  to do the :

```
startservice --user 0 -n com.android.shellms/.sendSMS -e contact "$i" -e msg "$2" 1>/dev/null
```

nowing that `$i` will be `%%a` and `$2` will be `%2`

Comment: Thanks! that helped greatly, this was was worked



for %%a in (%~1) do ( ECHO %%a & adb shell am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.shellms/.sendSMS -e contact %%a -e msg %2 )

script.bat "123123,123123" "message"  (to run)

Thanks!!